# Fiddler decrypt from all process causing site to not load

Tags: encryption, httprequest, fiddler

I have fiddler set to decrypt https request. But for some reason, the site I'm trying to check, always fail when I set it to decrypt "from all processes".

The decrypt https only seem to work with that option - as I get the "tunnel to" stuff, so it's my only choice to see the encrypted contents.

Any way to fix this - or know what's wrong with it? I can't find anything that explains what might be wrong. I know for a fact, it was working a few days ago. If the ssl cert was changed for the site - might that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What does `always fail` mean, specifically?

What browser or client are you using?

Have you configured Windows to trust Fiddler's root certificate?

No, Fiddler doesn't care about the remote site's certificate, unless the remote certificate is invalid and you click the `Don't continue` button shown in Fiddler.